# Prism & MEF access to composed objects

Tags: prism, mef

I am using Prism 4.0 with MEF. My application uses the [ImportingConstructor] attribute on its classes to construct objects. I need to gain access to the objects constructed. I believe Prism has a list of all the objects it created. Help me find the SomeObjectListSomewhere as shown below.

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly INoob _noob;

    [ImportingConstructor]  
    public Foo(INoob noob)
    {
        _noob = noob
    }
}

public class NotNoob
{
    public GoAction()
    {
        // I need Access to all INoob constructed objects here
        foreach (INoob noob in SomeObjectListSomewhere)
        {
             noob.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something simple like

```
[ImportMany]
IEnumerable<INoob> Noobs { get; set; }
```

Then use the `Noobs` collection and simply loop through the list like you do in `GoAction()`.